# a peculiar case of Outlook interop reference leaking

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

Even after my best efforts I still leak interop references, evident by Outlook not closing by itself. I have reduced my problem to the smallest possible sample and identified the line at fault, **can you spot what I am missing**?

FinalReleaseComObjectSafe takes an object and calls System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o) on it if it isn't null.

```
Outlook.Application app = null;
Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
Outlook.MAPIFolder explorerFolder = null;
Outlook.Explorers explorers = null;
Outlook.Explorer explorer = null;           

try
{
    app = new Outlook.Application();
    ns = app.Session;
    explorerFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);    
    explorers = app.Explorers;
    explorer = explorers.Add(explorerFolder); // If I omit this line Outlook closes by itself
}
finally
{   
    CSharpUtilities.FinalReleaseComObjectSafe(explorer);
    CSharpUtilities.FinalReleaseComObjectSafe(explorers);
    CSharpUtilities.FinalReleaseComObjectSafe(explorerFolder);
    CSharpUtilities.FinalReleaseComObjectSafe(ns);
    CSharpUtilities.FinalReleaseComObjectSafe(app);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Quit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866010.aspx) method of the Application class to close the application. Do you have any add-ins running in Outlook?

First of all, I'd suggest using the **ReleaseComObject** method instead. The FinalReleaseComObject may introduce new bugs if anybody else continue using an object referenced/released. There is no need to use GC's methods to force swiping the heap. The [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article states the following:

> Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object.

Where and when do you run the code?

Comment: Calling Quit prompts the "Do you want to delete all files in the deleted files folder?" dialog, so it's not an option. This code could be called at random times to collect contacts. Outlook might be running or not when the method is called. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/nEZAHyyf

Comment: My application usually runs 24/7, which is why I am executing all my interop code in a separate appdomain to avoid memory leaks in relation to Outlook Interop. Outlook is behaving weirdly though and does eventually freeze/crash after calling this method and others like it several times...

Comment: My reference cleaning seems to be mostly working: At first I had the Exception about too many opened Exchange objects quite often, but it doesn't occur anymore right now. I do get OutOfMemoryException with "the outlook window can not be opened, try closing windows or programs and try again"  though (There is enough memory available though).

Comment: Do you automate Outlook on the server side?

Comment: I wouldn't dare to (; What I am doing is collecting local Outlook contacts, public outlook contacts and Global Address List contacts (via Outlook and not via DirectorySearcher) to display them in a zero configuration phonebook / dialing assistant / calling notification tool. EWS is explicitly out of question as users having to know their Outlook details is deemed impractical. It's working: I can successfully collect all contacts! But I'd really like to avoid any Outlook freezes and crashes, which I supposed stem from my code leaking references.

Comment: I took a look at your code at pastebin.com. You need to review the code to release all underlying COM objects.